# Wrong payment method in order totals

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, payment, order-totals

I have received an order where user chose "Bank Transfer" as payment method but in order totals I've found "Cash on delivery" as payment method (by selecting this payment method user has to pay an extra fee).
The order totals are now wrong because of this extra fee.
why do I find a payment method that the user did not select in order totals section?
I've analyzed other orders with bank transfer payment method but they have not this issue.